# Why are no validation errors shown with an Ajax form in my MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog, jquery-validate

What is wrong if no validation errors are shown when the submitted data is null/empty? An error should be shown.

In the code block `result.success == false`, should I reload the view or tell jQuery to invalidate my model?

From my `Post` action in the controller I return the model errors so I have them on the client side.

What should I do now?

I am using MVC 3.0 with latest jQuery/UI 1.7.2/1.8.20:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        // the div holds the html content
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'This is the dialogs title',
            height: 400,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            hide: "fade",
            show: "fade",
            open: function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load('@Url.Action("Create")');
            },
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    var form = $('form', this);               

                    $.ajax({
                        url: $(form).attr('action'),
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: form.serialize(),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (result) {
                           // debugger;
                            if (result.success) {
                                $dialog.dialog("close");
                                // Update UI
                            }
                            else {
                                // Reload the dialog to show model/validation errors 


                            } // else end
                        } // success end
                    }); // Ajax post end

                },
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            } // no comma
        });

        $('#CreateTemplate').click(function () {
            $dialog.dialog('open');
            // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

my form is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("JsonCreate", "Template")) 
{  
    <p class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)</p> 
    <p class="editor-field">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)</p> 
    <p class="editor-field">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)</p>     
}
```

My controller is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{          
    return PartialView();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonCreate(Template template)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _templateDataProvider.AddTemplate(template);
        // success == true should be asked on client side and then ???
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }

        // return the same view with model when errors exist
        return PartialView(template);
}
```

The working version is:

I changed this in my `$.ajax` request:

```
// dataType: 'json', do not define the dataType let the jQuery infer the type !
data: form.serialize(),
success: function (result)
{
    debugger;
    if (result.success) {
        $dialog.dialog("close");
        // Update UI with Json data          
    }
    else {
        // Reload the dialog with the form to show model/validation errors 
        $dialog.html(result);
    }
} // success end
```

The Post action has to look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonCreate(Template template)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        return PartialView("Create", template);
        _templateDataProvider.AddTemplate(template);
        return Json(new { success = true });
    }
}
```

Either return the partialview which is the form `(success == false)` or return the JSON which is `success == true`.

Someone could still return a list of items to update the UI on client side:

```
return Json(new { success = true, items = list});
```

Comment: can you post the form code so we can see what you are trying to validate?

Comment: I updated the code with my form.

Comment: Is this IE8 by chance that you are experiencing this problem in?

Answer (score 0):

You got to make sure you are returning a JSON data and not html or any other kind of data. Use the browsers console to find out more about your ajax request and response to be sure that you are getting the right response, as you expect.

Comment: I return an ActionResult which can be JSON or HTML. On client side I check for success==true(JSON) else I did return PartialView() in the controller. What is wrong about that approach?

Answer (score 0):

well, the mistake I see is --

you are doing a return in the controller, you are supposed to do a

```
Response.Write(Json(new { success = true, items = list}));
```

Comment: are you that sure!!?? may be you should give it a shot. Ajax request looks for the output as response, not return value